# Apex Data Loader is loading previous date

Tags: data-loader, datetime, timezone

Apex Data loader is loading previous date.

- Salesforce Organization Default Time Zone is GMT+05:30
- Salesforce User Time Zone is GMT+05:30
- Apex Data Loader time zone is GMT+05:30
- CSV, for Apex Data Loader, has date as 2013-01-01
- Salesforce is showing 12/31/2012

Is this an Apex Data Loader bug, or am I missing something? Is is time to move to a different Data Loader?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not a bug. This is documented, make sure your source file has the dates with this format. (Specify the time)

YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005099&language=en_US

Comment: Thank for your time and answer. What is the `T` and `Z` in your DateTime format? Can you give me a sample DateTime in the format which you have mentioned? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It specifies the time of the day and time zone.  See this http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats. 
By the way, you will help other users by marking the original answer as such :)

Answer (score 0):

TO be more specific, the date has to be `YYYY-MM-DDT05:30:00Z` ! Otherwise, the date would be still 1 day behind.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing all of your csv data, try to go into the settings of Apex Data Loader and change the timezone to GMT